# Wont able to use preg_replace on a large string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to get rid of some word that is inside a `<note>` tag. I have a quite long string

`string(4687) "~~PB~~ {{:en:iot-open:remotelab:logotyp_1_.png?200|}} <note>testtest</note> ====== RoofTop Thermo Laboratory - intelligent house and heating management ====== The laboratory is located at nowhere, xxx, xxxxx on the roof of bu......`
 => *dumped result*

**The problem is that It wont remove this `testtest` string from between the `note` tag**

I'm trying to use this function that I found in the manual of strip_tags.

```
      function strip_tags_content($text, $tags = '', $invert = FALSE) {

  preg_match_all('/<(.+?)[\s]*\/?[\s]*>/si', trim($tags), $tags);
  $tags = array_unique($tags[1]);

  if(is_array($tags) AND count($tags) > 0) {
    if($invert == FALSE) {
      return preg_replace('@<(?!(?:'. implode('|', $tags) .')\b)(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
    else {
      return preg_replace('@<('. implode('|', $tags) .')\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    }
  }
  elseif($invert == FALSE) {
    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
  }
  return $text;
}
```

Here is my full code

```
foreach ($data as $line)
        {
            // Find list tag
            $posi = strpos($line, "* ");

            // No list ?
            if ($posi === false) {
                continue;
            }

            // Check indent
            if (($posi % 2) != 0){
                //echo "<li>Invalid indentation in TOC</li>\n";
            }

            // Calculate indent
            $indent = ($posi - 2) / 2;
            // Search for header
            $posh = strpos($line, "]]");

            // No header ?
            if ($posh === false) {
                continue;
            }
            // Extract file path
            $page_path = substr($line, $posi + 4, $posh - $posi - 4);
            $file_path = str_replace(":", "/", $page_path);
            $file_path = $this->getConf("homelab_datapages_folder").$file_path.".txt";
      $indent2 = 0;


            // Page file exists ?
            if (file_exists($file_path))
            {
                // Open file
                $page_content = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file_path));
        $page_content = $this->strip_tags_content($page_content,'note',TRUE);
        $page_cont = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($page_content));
                // Shorten header
                $book_content .= $this->shorten_header($page_content, $indent, $indent2)."\n";

        var_dump($book_content);
        //$book_content .=
      }
            else
            {
                $book_content .= "---\n MISSING PAGE ---\n";
            }

            // Display page
            //echo "    <li>".$page_path." (".$indent.")</li>\n";
        }
```

What could be the problem?

Is my string too long to use preg_replase or I'm making a mistake here?

Comment: If I am reading it correctly your string is 4687 bytes long, that's not too long for `preg_replace()`. So clearly something else must be wrong. You've got `strip_tags_content($page_content,'note',TRUE)` whereas, if I follow the examples given, it should read `strip_tags_content($page_content,'<note>',TRUE)`. I'm absolutely not sure if it will work when you do that, that's why this is a comment, and not an answer.

Comment: tried to use <> tag, but with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got It working.

The problem was with the `htmlspecialchars()` function.

`$page_content = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file_path));`

to

```
$page_content = file_get_contents($file_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling

```
$this->strip_tags_content($page_content,'note',TRUE);
```

the preg_match_all results with an empty array `$tags`, so all the tests after are false and the return value is allways `$text` without any modifications.

Call the function:

```
$this->strip_tags_content($page_content,'<note>',TRUE);
//                                       ^____^
```

Comment: I tried, but with no result. It will work if  i'll create a new variable like $test= " test test <note>TEST</note>" result=> test test

Comment: @Godhaze: Of course, you have to assign a new variable.Your function doesn't work in place.

Comment: What you mean by that, I just changed the code like that:         $test = "test TEST <note>not TEST</note>";
    //$page_content = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file_path));
        $page_content1 = $this->strip_tags_content($test,'<note>',TRUE);
        //$page_cont = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($page_content));
    // Shorten header
    //$book_content .= $this->shorten_header($page_cont, $indent, $indent2)."\n";

        var_dump($page_content1);

Comment: @Godhaze: Sorry but I don't get you. If you call the function with the parameter `<note>` instead of `note`, it works fine with the sample text you've given. You should add some debug lines in your code to see where it fails.